# Drawn line is offset from mouse pointer

Tags: html, canvas

If I scroll down to see bottom part of canvas the drawing function still works, but the line comes not from the mouse pointer. http://flamencopeko.net/draw.php http://flamencopeko.net/draw.txt

```
<canvas id = "can" width = "715" height = "715" 
    style = "position: relative; border: 1px solid; background: #FFFFFF;">
</canvas>
```

Issue is cross-browser.

Comment: I think you need to check your `findxy` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your findxy function uses the absolute position of the canvas, which does not change when you scoll, however clientX/clientY does change relative to the canvas.

You can instead used information from getBoundingClientRect() to move the mouse coordinates into canvas coordinate space.

Try this:

```
function findxy(res, e) {
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

if (res == 'down') {
    prevX = currX;
    prevY = currY;
    currX = e.clientX  - rect.left;
    currY = e.clientY - rect.top

    flag = true;
    dot_flag = true;
    if (dot_flag) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = x;
        ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
        ctx.closePath();
        dot_flag = false;
    }
}
if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
    flag = false;
}
if (res == 'move') {
    if (flag) {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.clientX - rect.left;
        currY = e.clientY - rect.top
        draw();
    }
}
```

}

getBoundingClientRect() will fetch the coordinates of your canvas relative to the view port (The same as clientX/clientY), so it is not affected by scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I was pretty sure I knew what the problem here was, but I had a quick look at your site to make sure. So all you need to do is add how much the window has been scrolled. From what I could see it should be inserted inside your findxy() function like so:

```
currX = window.pageXOffset + e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
currY = window.pageYOffset + e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
```

So to explain, the clientX and clientY values from the event object calculate the mouse position relative to the top left of the user's screen, not the entire page. That is why we need to also add the page offset values from the window object.